# Referencing UserClaims in an Entity Framework Core class

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a data project with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core.  We're starting to use user claims (Identity) to manage authorization for things like managers etc. Previously, we had a separate table for managers, so that each permission could be set on each object and we looked it up as required.

Simple example prior to UserClaims:

```
Store                { StoreId, Name etc... plus ICollection<ManagerPermissions> }
User                 { StoreId, Name, Email etc}
ManagerPermissions   { StoreId, UserId }
```

Using the separate `ManagerPermissions` table meant it was easy to list the relevant manager(s) for that store by using a navigation property like `ICollection<ManagerPermissions>`. If writing a query, I could do `_context.Store.Include(s => s.ManagerPermissions)` to include a list of managers to display.

Now that we're using user claims, I haven't found an easy way to do this.  I've extended IdentityDbContext so the claims data is held within the same database as the other data.

I have seen

```
UserManager.GetUsersWithClaimAsync({ ClaimType="ismanager", ClaimValue = StoreId})
```

but this requires an instance of `userManager` and also a separate roundtrip to the database. The only other way I could think of is by doing a join on `UserClaims` table, but I'm not sure the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Take a look at [Add navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-navigation-properties) sections of the [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It's not so easy, but once done, you'll have user claims collection navigation property in your identity user class, which you can easily query (or simply `Include`) similar to your previous model.

Comment: Whether you use `UserClaim` or a custom query, the database is finally handling a join query. And I don't think you have to use `UserClaim`, your `ManagerPermissions` should be enough. By the way, you can simply access a `UserManager` instance with DI, just put is as a parameter of your constructor.